# Bringing my lables and buttons to front

Tags: ios, ipad, ios4, subview

I have a TableView in my main view. This table view hides some of lables and buttons in main view. After selecting a row from TableView  table has to `removeFromSuperView` and buttons must be visible.

```
       - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
          UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
          txtsearch.text = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
           [viewForautoCompleteTableView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.view sendSubviewToBack:autocompleteTableView];
           }
```

Still my lables are not visible, thank you.

Comment: before adding the tableview to self.view were they visible ?

Comment: Just for debugging purpose : set the textcolor of labels to white and setbackground color of your self.view to orange

Answer (score 0):

It's better to hide and show the views rather than remove and add the views to achieve the effect you want.

Make sure all the views have been added properly to self.view. To hide them use:

```
viewForautoCompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
autocompleteTableView.hidden = YES;
```

To make them show you can use:

```
viewForautoCompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: and some part of my label is visible